# En un diagrama ER ¿Puede una enridad débil relacionarse con dos entidades a la vez?

Tags: base-de-datos

escribo para consultar acerca de si una entidad débil puede relacionarse con dos entidades a la vez. El primer diagrama resuelve la regla de negocio del enunciado pero no permite obtener el cliente que realizo la transacción (ya que muchos clientes pueen disponer de la misma cuenta). Al implementar este requisito en el segundo diagrama, la entidad débil adquiere otra relación. ¿Es posible o ya la entidad débil deja de serlo?

[image: Imagen del diagrama]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, la condicion para que una entidad sea considerada debil es que deba cumplir con la dependencia existencial hacia otra entidad.Pero eso no la limita a relacionarse con otras entidades.

Por lo tanto, transaccion en este caso seria considerada debil de cuenta y tambien podria estar relacionada con Cliente.Para poder representar esto en el diagrama deberias utilizar la doble linea que representaria la participacion total y el rombo de "ejecuta" tambien deberia estar contenido en una doble linea.

Comment: Hola Santino, gracias por tu tiempo. Entonces doble línea desde ejecuta a Transacción y doble línea al rombo ejecuta. ¿No corre lo mismo para hace con Cliente?

Comment: Exacto, esa es la notacion con la que a mi me dijeron que debia representar las relaciones de las entidades debiles.